# Simulate printing in ZPL

Tags: compact-framework, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

Is it possible to try a Windows Mobile application made with ZPL without an actual printer? Like simulate the printing?

Also, is there any site/videoes/books about Zebra Programming Language for beginners?

Comment: Since the [PrintDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.printing.printdocument(v=vs.80).aspx) control is not supported in the Compact Framework, you'll most likely have to create a new, blank form, override the `OnPaint` method, and draw out your form on the control to see any preview.

Comment: Oops! Just noticed the [PrintDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.printdialog.printdocument(v=vs.85).aspx) **is** supported in Compact Framework 3.0 - you might want to look into that. Writing a `Document_Print` routine is easier to preview then send to a printer.

Comment: Yes going the PrintDocument path has been one of my options. If I go on to this, how do I create a "document" or a "report" that I can send to the Document_Print in Windows Mobile? Ill be printing with labels that include Bar Codes.

Comment: Zebra has several WYSIWYG label design products that will then give you access to the actual ZPL command stream.  Instead of sending, effectively, images of barcodes to the printer for example, you send a 23 byte string to the printer and it renders the barcode.

Comment: Bartender also supports this functionality.  Perhaps NiceLabel does too, not as familiar with their full feature set.

Comment: Yes Im actually using Zebra Designer 2 for designing the labes. When I print them, I use a text file as a port so the ZPL codes are sent to a text file. I then use the ZPL codes for my .NET CF code. But I have no way of testing if the ZPL codes Im sending are correct because I dont have a printer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm learning ZPL from [here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf): it's provided by Zebra Website. I think it's very helpfull.

If you want simulate the printing, you can use [labelary](http://labelary.com/viewer.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at my question and answer on [PrintPage PrintPageEventHandler Is Printing Too Many Copies](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10287558/153923).

My issue was printing from a Windows Form, but you could do the same thing with Windows Mobile.

What you do is create a dummy Form with the same proportions as the document you want to print. Set labels all around with what you want them to say. Some fields will need to be INPUT fields so that your Windows Mobile app can call them and fill in those values.

For example, if you had a customer address you needed to set, the label on your dummy Form would be `lblCustomerStreet`, `lblCustomerCity`, `lblCustomerState`, and `lblCustomerZip` with **public** properties:

```
public string CustomerStreet {
  get { return lblCustomerStreet.Text; }
  set { lblCustomerStreet.Text = value; }
}
```

When you need to print, you make a ratio of your Form's size to the PrintDocument's Page Size. You use that ratio to either increase or decrease the size of the label so that the text fits on the page.

It does take some time to do, and there is a lot of trial and error involved.

However, the question and answer I posted up at the top will get you about 80% of the way. You would only be interested in focusing on the **Document_Printed** section of my code.

My example code included sizing for Panel controls, Label controls, one Image control (company logo), as well as a custom Barcode control that you can delete. The Image is printed first, then the Panels, then Labels, and finally the Barcode - because in my printout, the Barcodes are the most important, and the text on the labels is more important than the box lines made by the Panels. Panels just make your printout look pretty.

Comment: I guess Ill be going to the approach you suggested. Since our client did not provide a printer and doesnt even want to provide a remote PC I can access their printer's website for label output preview.

Can you give me a headstart of capturing the form on my Windows Mobile and sending it to the printer for printing?